# How do I view the params that OAuth is using to build its signature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, signature

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 with this gem …

```
gem 'oauth'
```

I”m using this code to verify the signature being passed from a third party ..

```
require 'oauth/request_proxy/action_controller_request'
…
@oauth_signature_validator = OAuth::Signature.build(request, :consumer_secret => consumer_secret)
result = @oauth_signature_validator.verify()
```

However validation repeatedly fails.  How can I see what OAuth::Signature request params are being used to compute and compare signatures?  I have verified that the consumer secret is correct and that everything is set up properly from the third party that is sending the signatures.

Comment: Try raising an error and converting the response to yaml in your controller. This should give you a formatted output.

Comment: I don't understand how to figure out my answer from your suggestion.  No exceptions are thrown by the abofe, wehter the signature validates or not.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but if you're trying to inspect the OAuth request and response, you can do that with my [httplog](https://github.com/trusche/httplog) gem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool such as`byebug`, `pry` or `pry-remote` to get a console session before `@oauth_signature_validator`.

To do this add either:

- `gem "byebug"`
- `gem "pry"`
- `gem "pry-remote"`

to your Gemfile then run `bundle install`. Then, above the line in question add:

- `byebug` (for `byebug`)
- `binding.pry` (for `pry`)
- `binding.remote_pry` (for `pry-remote`)

For the first two, it will drop you into a ruby shell when it hits the line, allowing you to inspect the request object. For `pry-remote` it will pause your application, requiring you to (in another shell) run `bundle exec pry-remote` in the application directory.